# ScreenCapture.bat Without Window Title

Tags: display, batch, capture

How can i make this script capture foreground window without The title ?

https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/screenCapture.bat

I need it so i can continue on a delphi project without having to change all var's coordinates.

I know it's possible cause i have a screenshot() function on my delphi app that let's me choose between

```
  GetWindowRect(Win, WinRect);
  DC := GetWindowDC(Win);
```

OR

```
  Windows.GetClientRect(Win, WinRect);
  DC := GetDC(Win);
```

I just don't know how to do it in this batch.

Comment: What you can do in BASH and what you can do with Delphi are two entirely different things.

Comment: This script uses the same WinApi i call on Delphi, so i thought it was possible.

Comment: You abuse a batch file to execute .net code. I think you should ask your question on Stack Overflow instead. They are more likely to help you as this is not really about .bat programming, but more about .net programming